# Looking for Alarm / Monitoring tool that is time of day aware

Tags: monitoring

I have some metrics that are variable based on time of day (such as number of user logins).  I would like to setup some alarms that trigger if the value is too high or too low compared to an expected value.

The expected values are different based on the time of day (e.g. we expect a lot of logins during the daytime, and fewer at night).  This applies to more than just logins....

Is there any sort of tool that helps with this?  Currently for our monitoring we are using a combination of CloudWatch and ServerDensity.

Comment: Any tool with an api + a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios has "time periods" which you can define different alert levels and notification levels for.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg8/amazon_cloudwatch_sensor

For cloudwatch at least (you'll have to check for ServerDensity) it appears you can create schedules for alarms/monitors.

So create one that only runs for a timeframe based on certain metrics, and then another for another timeframe, etc.

NOTE:  sorry...I might be mistaken...you can try but the schedule might be for all alarms, etc.  Definitely try in the account settings first though.